# Adding up a score through IF-statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to build a script where the user has to rank certain words. I'm trying to keep the score uo to date but it keeps coming out wrong. When I test the code and I answer AB, the outcome of orientaal equals 5. The outcome should be orientaal = 3 and bloemig = 2. This is the code I made (I'm not very experienced):

```
var orientaal = 0;
var houtig = 0;
var bloemig = 0;
var aromatisch = 0;
var chypre = 0;
var citrus = 0;

var q1 = prompt('Welk element spreekt jou het meest aan? Zet de letters van hoog naar laag (Bijv. DBAC). \n A. Vuur \n B. Lucht \n C. Aarde \n D. Water')

if(q1.charAt(0) == 'A' || 'a') {
  orientaal = orientaal + 3;
}else if(q1.charAt(0) == 'B' || 'b') {
  bloemig = bloemig + 3;
}else if(q1.charAt(0) == 'C' || 'c') {
  houtig = houtig + 3;
}else if(q1.charAt(0) == 'D' || 'd') {
  citrus = citrus + 3;
}

if(q1.charAt(1) == 'A' || 'a') {
  orientaal = orientaal + 2;
}else if(q1.charAt(1) == 'B' || 'b') {
  bloemig = bloemig + 2;
}else if(q1.charAt(1) == 'C' || 'c') {
  houtig = houtig + 2;
}else if(q1.charAt(1) == 'D' || 'd') {
  citrus = citrus + 2;
}

console.log('orientaal = ' + orientaal);
console.log('houtig = ' + houtig);
console.log('bloemig = ' + bloemig);
console.log('aromatisch = ' + aromatisch);
console.log('chypre = ' + chypre);
console.log('citrus = ' + citrus);
```

Comment: `if(q1.charAt(0) == 'A' || 'a')` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: change like this in if statement if(q1.charAt(1) == 'A' || q1.charAt(1) == 'a')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if(q1.charAt(0) == 'A' || 'a')` does not do what you think it does. Specifically, this says

> if the first character of `q1` is `'A'`, or `'a'` is truthy

Since the second half is always true (all strings are truthy except the empty-string), you'll always get a pass there.

Instead, consider using `switch` as follows:

```
switch(q1[0]) { // strings can be accessed as arrays of characters
  case 'A':
  case 'a':
    orientaal += 3;
    break;
  case 'B':
  case 'b':
    // .......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `switch` and set the char to lower case to avoid the double check for `A` and `a`

```js
var orientaal = 0;
var houtig = 0;
var bloemig = 0;
var aromatisch = 0;
var chypre = 0;
var citrus = 0;

var q1 = prompt('Welk element spreekt jou het meest aan? Zet de letters van hoog naar laag (Bijv. DBAC). \n A. Vuur \n B. Lucht \n C. Aarde \n D. Water');

switch(q1[0].toLowerCase()){
  case 'a':
    orientaal+=3;
    break;
  case 'b':
    bloemig+=3;
    break;
  case 'c':
    houtig+=3;
    break;
  case 'd':
    citrus+=3;
    break;
}

console.log('orientaal = ' + orientaal);
console.log('houtig = ' + houtig);
console.log('bloemig = ' + bloemig);
console.log('aromatisch = ' + aromatisch);
console.log('chypre = ' + chypre);
console.log('citrus = ' + citrus);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ranking is always the same, namely the top answer will get +3, the second +2, the 3rd +1 and the last one +0 to its associated actegory, you can simplify this whole calculation by just using some data structures.
Basically, you only need to associate each possible answer with a category and then count all the scores together.

The big advantage is that you can just add questions and categories without changing the rest of the code. Else you would have to write the whole if/else logic again for each question you add, and edit ALL the if/else you already have, if you add a category.

Just showing the principle here. The code should be expanded with checking the user input better. And obv use the questions you yourself have. Etc.

```
    // Array with all used categories
var categories = [
        'orientaal',
        'houtig',
        'bloemig',
        'aromatisch',
        'chypre',
        'citrus'
    ],
    // Array containing all the questions and the category of each answer
    questions = [
        {
            'text' : 'Welk element spreekt jou het meest aan? Zet de letters van hoog naar laag (Bijv. DBAC).',
            'answers' : {
                'A' : {
                    'val' : 'Vuur',
                    'category' : 'orientaal'
                },
                'B' : {
                    'val' : 'Lucht',
                    'category' : 'bloemig'
                },
                'C' : {
                    'val' : 'Aarde',
                    'category' : 'houtig'
                },
                'D' : {
                    'val' : 'Water',
                    'category' : 'citrus'
                }
            }
        }, {
            'text' : 'Welk dier spreekt jou het meeste aan?',
            'answers' : {
                'A' : {
                    'val' : 'Draak',
                    'category' : 'orientaal'
                },
                'B' : {
                    'val' : 'Arend',
                    'category' : 'aromatisch'
                },
                'C' : {
                    'val' : 'Wolf',
                    'category' : 'houtig'
                },
                'D' : {
                    'val' : 'Slang',
                    'category' : 'chypre'
                }
            }
        }, {
            'text' : 'Welke locatie spreekt je het meeste aan?',
            'answers' : {               
                'A' : {
                    'val' : 'Dennenbos',
                    'category' : 'houtig'
                },
                'B' : {
                    'val' : 'Steppe',
                    'category' : 'orientaal'
                },
                'C' : {
                    'val' : 'Oerwoud',
                    'category' : 'citrus'
                },
                'D' : {
                    'val' : 'Heide',
                    'category' : 'bloemig'
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    // Array to save the answers of the user.
    userAnswers = [],
    // Var to create the results.
    scoreList;

// Let's 'fake' an interface that asks the questions. Replace this with your own form and functions that push the answers to the userAnswers array.
questions.forEach(function( questionObj, index ) {
        // Create the text for the possible answers from our questionObject.
    var answerText = Object.keys(questionObj.answers).map(function( letter ) {
            // We just return the letter, plus a dot, plus the value corresponding with that letter.
            return letter + '.: ' + questionObj.answers[ letter ].val;
        }).join(', '),
        // Ask the question, using the text inside our questionObj.
        prompt = window.prompt('Vraag ' + (index + 1) + ': ' + questionObj.text + ' ' + answerText, '');
    // Check if a 'valid' answer was entered. This should be expanded to also check that the input consists of some combination of ABCD
    // if (prompt && prompt.length === 4) userAnswers.push( prompt );
    // else alert('Gelieve alle 4 de letters in volgorde te zetten');
    // But for now we'll just accept any answer for testing purposes.
    userAnswers.push( prompt );
});
// Now let's check the score of the answers. We can reduce the users' answers into one value object that we can create by reducing our categories into a 'score list': A plain object with the category as the key adn the count as the value.
scoreList = userAnswers.reduce(function( scoreList, answer, index ) {
    // Since our answers are in the same order as our questions, we can just use the idnex to get the question associated with this answer.
    var questionObj = questions[ index ],
        // By splitting the answer, we get an array containing the 4 individual letters.
        answerLetters = answer.split('');
    // For each letter that is part of the answer, add the correct value to our score list.
    answerLetters.forEach(function( letter, index ) {
        // The answered letter gives us the correct category
        var category = questionObj.answers[ letter ].category;
        // We can just use a static array to transform the index into the score: index 0 = score 3, i1 = s2, i2 = s1, i3 = s0
        scoreList[ category ] += [ 3, 2, 1, 0 ][ index ];
    });
    return scoreList;
}, categories.reduce(function( scoreList, category ) {
    scoreList[ category ] = 0;
    return scoreList;
}, {}));
// Report the results
alert( JSON.stringify( scoreList ) );
```